# Get Choice Description in queryset.value_list django

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-queryset

I have a model and within it I have IntegerChoice Class (Gender)

When I get field value with values_list() I don't want to get value as a number (1 or 2) but as a label string (Female or Male)

models.py:

```
class Policy(models.Model):
    class Gender(models.IntegerChoices):
        MALE = 1, _("Male")
        FEMALE = 2, _("Female")

    maca = models.CharField(max_length=100, db_column="Maca", null=True, blank=True)
    gender = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(
        db_column="Gender",
        choices=Gender.choices,
        blank=True,
        null=True,
    )
```

views.py

```
Policy.objects.all().values_list("maca", "gender")
```

Answer (score 0):

Please don't use [**`.values_list(…)`** <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#values-list), it erodes the "model layer", and as a result, you can indeed no longer obtain the text. I wrote [an article <sup>[Django-antipatterns]</sup>](https://www.django-antipatterns.com/antipattern/over-use-of-values.html) that discusses the main problem(s) with this.

You do this with the [**`.get_fieldname_display(…)`** method <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/instances/#django.db.models.Model.get_FOO_display), so here `get_gender_display`:

```
my_policy.get_gender_display()
```

with `my_policy` is a `Policy` object.

or in a template, you can use:

```
{{ my_policy.get_gender_display }}
```

and in a serializer you can use:

```
from rest_framework import serializers


class PolicySerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    gender = serializers.CharField(source='get_gender_display')

    class Meta:
        model = Policy
        fields = ('gender',)
```